# Simular Click com webview em um href

Tags: javascript

```
<li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="tb_next"
  <a href="#" aria-controls="tb" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Seguinte</a>
</li>
```

Olá amigos, tenho uma pagina que tem esse codigo html e preciso simular um click nesse href, a simulação eu já consigo via webview (javafx)

```
webEngine.executeScript(
  "document.getElementById(\"botão\").click();"
);
```

Mas como voces podem ver só existe ID no element pai e ai não estou conseguindo acessar o element filho href.

Eu tentei assim, mas não esta dando certo:

```
webEngine.executeScript(
  "document.getElementById(\"tb_next\").firstChild.click();"
);
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar por favor, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.querySelector` onde você consegue mais facilmente selecionar o `<a>` dentro da `<li>` em questão:

```
document.querySelector("#tb_next a").click();
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.querySelector("#tb_next a").click();
```

```html
<li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="tb_next">
   <a href="javascript: alert('ok')" aria-controls="tb" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">Seguinte</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Obg Amigos, pela pronta ajuda, mas será que teria alguma solução feita em javascript, não sei porque mas o meu programa não esta conseguindo executar JQuery.

Comment: vejam as msgs de erros: 
TypeError: document.querySelectorAll("#tb_next > .page-link").click 
is not a function. (In 'document.querySelectorAll("#tb_next > .page-link").click()', 
'document.querySelectorAll("#tb_next > .page-link").click' is undefined)

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#tb_next a").click')

Comment: Amigo, minha resposta não utiliza jQuery. Creio que a outra resposta esteja incorreta.

Answer (score -1):

eu faço utilizando o `querySelectorAll`

o ex de seleção seria algo assim

```
webEngine.executeScript(
  "document.querySelectorAll(\"#tb_next > .page-link\").click();"
);
```

ele executaria o click em todos `.page-link` que tiverem dentro de um `#tb_next`